# How to write type definitions for React HoCs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I have a higher order component that deals with Firestore data for me. I'm pretty new to typescript and I'm having trouble getting the types to work as I'd like them to.

**[Here are the full files + some extra ts definitions](https://gist.github.com/strass/2a764d1f70e2ef9a185d3063c5dbfeca)**

I have a couple problems:

**React.Component not inferring type definitions:**

```
type WithFirestoreHoC<Props = {}> = (
  config: WithFirestoreConfig<Props>,
) => (
  WrappedComponent: ComponentType<WithFirestore & Props>,
) => ComponentClass<Props, { error: Error; queries: {}; loaded: boolean }>;

const withFirestore: WithFirestoreHoC = ({
  queries,
  props: propPickList,
  loading: { delay = 200, timeout = 0 } = {},
}) => WrappedComponent =>
  class WithFirestoreConnect extends Component { ... }
```

`config` and `WrappedComponent` are getting their type definitions (as `WithFirestoreConfig` + `ComponentType<WithFirestore & Props>`, respectively.

However, `WithFirestoreConnect` is not inferring that it should be `ComponentClass<Props, { error: Error; queries: {}; loaded: boolean }>`.

I wouldn't mind defining the state twice, but that doesn't help me with getting `Props` from `type WithFirestoreHoC<Props = {}>` to `class WithFirestoreConnect extends Component<Props, { error: Error; queries: {}; loaded: boolean }> { ... }` because it can't find `Props`.

**How to create a dynamic pick list**

Part of `WithFirestoreConfig` defines that the config object has a list of props that get passed on to `WrappedComponent`

`WrappedComponent: ComponentType<WithFirestore & Props>,`
should really be
`WrappedComponent: ComponentType<WithFirestore & Pick<Props, config.propsPickList>,`

Is there a way to tell typescript that what you provide in `config.propsPickList` will determine what props `WrappedComponent` should expect?

**Inferring Firestore types**

There are 2 types of Firestore query responses, those for Documents and those for Collections/Queries. It would be amazing if those could be defined in `config.queries` as something like this:

```
{ queries: { 
    docQuery: myDocument as DocumentReference<docDataType>, 
    collectionQuery: myDocument as CollectionReference<docDataType>,  
} }
```

so WrappedComponent could know whether to expect a query or document data structure on the other end.

This seems super complex so I have a simpler example (it's a shortcut that creates a single subscription) here that would at least be a good stepping stone towards what I want:

```
export const withFirestoreDocument: <
  DataType = firestore.DocumentData,
  Props = {}
>(
  query: FirestoreQueryable<DataType>,
) => (
  WrappedComponent: ComponentType<DocumentSnapshotExpanded<DataType>>,
) => WithFirestoreHoC<Props> = query => WrappedComponent =>
  withFirestore({ queries: { _default: query } })(
    mapProps<
      DocumentSnapshotExpanded<DataType> & Props,
      { _default: DocumentSnapshotExpanded<DataType> } & Props
    >(({ _default, ...props }) => ({ ...props, ..._default }))(WrappedComponent),
  );
```

However I'm stuck here because I can't get `mapProp`'s type definitions to pull from the function's type defs... What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**React.Component not inferring type definitions:** Make `Props` a type parameter of the function instead of the type alias and then declare it when you define `withFirestore`.

**How to create a dynamic pick list:** Add a `PL` type parameter for the union of the elements of the pick list.  This will do the right thing when you let TypeScript infer `PL` at a call site, though it's possible for callers to produce unsound behavior by specifying `PL` to be a union type including elements that are not in the actual list.

**Inferring Firestore types:** I'm not sure where you were going with `withFirestoreDocument`.  You can do this with another `Q` type parameter and some mapped types and conditional types to generate the types of the injected props from `Q`.

Here is my revision of `withFirestore.tsx` with all the new features, some unrelated fixes to get it to compile in my environment, and an example added at the bottom (which should probably rather be in a separate file):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component, ComponentClass, ComponentType } from 'react';
import {
  DocumentReference,
  Query,
  CollectionReference,
  DocumentSnapshotExpanded,
  QuerySnapshotExpanded
} from './firemodel';
import { firestore } from 'firebase';
import { pick, forEach, isEqual, isFunction } from 'lodash';
import { expandDocSnapshot, expandQuerySnapshot } from 'modules/providers/util';
import SmartLoader from 'modules/atoms/SmartLoader';

type FirestoreQueryable<DataType> =
  | DocumentReference<DataType>
  | Query<DataType>
  | CollectionReference<DataType>;

type FirestoryQueryableFunction<
  DataType,
  Props
> = (
  firestore: firestore.Firestore,
  props: Props,
) => Promise<FirestoreQueryable<DataType>>;

type QueryConfigEntry<Props> =
  FirestoreQueryable<any> | FirestoryQueryableFunction<any, Props>;

type QueryConfig<Props> = {
  [queryName: string]: QueryConfigEntry<Props>;
};

type FirestoreQueryableExpanded<Props, QE extends QueryConfigEntry<Props>> =
  QE extends FirestoreQueryable<any> ? FirestoreQueryableExpanded1<QE> :
  QE extends FirestoryQueryableFunction<any, Props> ? FirestoreQueryableExpanded1<ReturnType<QE>> : unknown;

type FirestoreQueryableExpanded1<QE extends FirestoreQueryable<any>> =
  QE extends CollectionReference<infer DataType> | Query<infer DataType> ? QuerySnapshotExpanded<DataType> :
  QE extends DocumentReference<infer DataType> ? DocumentSnapshotExpanded<DataType> : unknown;

interface WithFirestoreConfig<Props, PL extends keyof Props, Q extends QueryConfig<Props>> {
  /** Object containing the queries to be provided to WrappedComponent.
   * The queryName used is also the prop name the snapshot is passed in. */
  queries: Q;
  /** A list of props to whitelist passing to WrappedComponent.
   * Configs without a list will whitelist all props */
  props?: PL[];
  /** Loading config items */
  loading?: {
    /** Number of ms after which to display the loading icon */
    delay?: number;
    /** Number of ms after which to display the timeout message */
    timeout?: number;
  };
}

type WithFirestoreHoC = <Props>() => <PL extends keyof Props, Q extends QueryConfig<Props>>(
  config: WithFirestoreConfig<Props, PL, Q>,
) => (
  WrappedComponent: ComponentType<WithFirestore<Props, Q> & Pick<Props, PL>>,
) => ComponentClass<Props, { error: Error; queries: {}; loaded: boolean }>;

const withFirestore: WithFirestoreHoC =
  // An extra function call is needed so that callers can specify Props and
  // still have PL and Q inferred.  It can be removed when
  // https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571 is implemented.
  <Props extends {}>() =>
  // Note: if `props` is not passed, there will be no inference for PL and it
  // will default to its constraint, which is exactly the behavior we want as
  // far as typing is concerned.
  <PL extends keyof Props, Q extends QueryConfig<Props>>({
    queries,
    props: propPickList,
    loading: { delay = 200, timeout = 0 } = {},
  }: WithFirestoreConfig<Props, PL, Q>) => WrappedComponent =>
  class WithFirestoreConnect extends Component<Props, { error: Error; queries: WithFirestore<Props, Q>; loaded: boolean }> {
    subscriptions: {
      [queryName: string]: ReturnType<FirestoreQueryable<any>['onSnapshot']>;
    } = {};
    state = {
      error: null as Error,
      queries: {} as WithFirestore<Props, Q>,
      loaded: false,
    };
    componentDidMount() {
      this.restartSubscription();
    }

    cancelSubscriptions = () => {
      forEach(this.subscriptions, unsubscribe => unsubscribe());
      this.subscriptions = {};
    };

    restartSubscription = () => {
      // Open questions:
      //   - figuring out when all loaded (use a promise?)
      this.cancelSubscriptions();
      forEach(queries, async (q: QueryConfigEntry<Props>, key) => {
        let ref: FirestoreQueryable<any>;
        if (isFunction(q)) {
          // The fact that this is an async/await means that we can
          // create dependent queries within our FirestoreQueryableFunction
          ref = await q(firestore(), this.props);
        } else {
          // Narrowing is not working for some reason.
          ref = q as FirestoreQueryable<any>;
        }
        if (ref instanceof firestore.DocumentReference) {
          this.subscriptions[key] = ref.onSnapshot(
            snap => {
              this.setState({
                queries: Object.assign({}, this.state.queries, {[key]: expandDocSnapshot(snap)}),
              });
            },
            err => {
              console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
              this.setState({ error: err });
              this.cancelSubscriptions();
            },
          );
        } else if (
          ref instanceof firestore.CollectionReference ||
          ref instanceof firestore.Query
        ) {
          let ref2: {onSnapshot(os: (snap: firestore.QuerySnapshot) => void, oe: (err: Error) => void): () => void; } = ref;
          this.subscriptions[key] = ref2.onSnapshot(
            snap => {
              this.setState({
                queries: Object.assign({}, this.state.queries, {[key]: expandQuerySnapshot(snap)}),
              });
            },
            err => {
              console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
              this.setState({ error: err });
              this.cancelSubscriptions();
            },
          );
        }
      });
    };

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Props) {
      if (!isEqual(this.props, prevProps)) {
        this.restartSubscription();
      }
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.cancelSubscriptions();
    }
    render() {
      if (!this.state.loaded || this.state.error) {
        return (
          <SmartLoader
            error={this.state.error}
            timeout={timeout}
            delay={delay}
          />
        );
      }

      const whitelistedProps = propPickList
        ? pick(this.props, propPickList)
        : this.props;
      // Unsure what's wrong here ~ Matt
      let WrappedComponent2 = WrappedComponent as any;
      return <WrappedComponent2 {...whitelistedProps} {...this.state.queries} />;
    }
  };

export type WithFirestore<Props, Q extends QueryConfig<Props>> = {
  [queryName in keyof Q]: FirestoreQueryableExpanded<Props, Q[queryName]>;
}

export default withFirestore;

// EXAMPLE

interface MyDoc {
  y: number
}
declare let myDocRef: DocumentReference<MyDoc>;
declare let myCollRef: CollectionReference<MyDoc>;
let wrapped = withFirestore<{x: string}>()({
  queries: {
    myDoc: myDocRef,
    myColl: myCollRef
  },
})((props) => { return <>{props.myDoc.data.y + props.myColl.docs[props.x].data.y}</>; });
```

Comment: Wow, this was super helpful. It's working great and the typescript support is so much better than my first iteration.

However, I'm not sure if I learned anything because this is definitely too advanced for me. Do you know of any guides/tutorials on complex use of typescript + react?

Comment: This is all just advanced TypeScript type inference and manipulation and not specific to React.  I'd start with the examples in [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) for mapped and conditional types.  I don't have a resource to point to for the technique of introducing a type variable like `Q` or `PL` to retain type information, but that idea has come up many times on Stack Overflow.  If you have specific questions about the solution after you've gone through the handbook page, I'll be happy to answer them here.